# Connection refused on client and server, both are on MAC

Tags: ios, macos, sockets, connection

I am using Mac book and having client and server running on same machine. Server opens socket whenever it has to send command to Client. Problem is Client opens socket at startup   but whenever server opens on . Ip adress is different. I would like to know if i create tunnel between these 2 sockets. Right now, while in server i am getting "Connection refused" error.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use `127.0.0.1` loopback address for testing your initial socket code. Server `bind()`s and `listen()`s on some known port, client `connect()`s to it. Once you figure out that setup you can move on to routing between real addresses.